# Sorting CREATE TABLE statements, which contains references in Java

Tags: java, sorting, jdbc, annotations

my project is about to create my own persistence implementation. Maybe it's easy but I can't find the solution. I have Classes annotated with my own annotation @Entity and in Annotation Processor I want to create SQL create table statements and save them into file and then execute them. But how do I sort these statements? I have references in tables, I have to first create the non referencing table and then table referencing on this first table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Show what you've tried, and say what does happen and should happen

Comment: Sort them by ***what*** within the SQL String?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I will be concrete. Imagine you have for example 3 Classes: Person Department and Company. They are annotated as Entities and I want to create the SQL statements for create tables. But Company references on Department and Person references on Department, so I have to first create the Department table and then Person or Company. I am creating the statements in Annotation Processor, so I have for disposal the annotated elements. Now I am just sorting String to be written in file. But it isn't very pretty.

```
     ArrayList<String> sortedListOfCommands = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String command: listOfCommands){
            if(!command.contains("FOREIGN"))
                sortedListOfCommands.add(command);
        }

        for(String command: listOfCommands){
            if(!sortedListOfCommands.contains(command))
                sortedListOfCommands.add(command);
        }
```